# Show RSS Feeds of IE as Screensaver

Tags: rss, screensaver

Is there a way I can display the rss feeds that I have subsribed to using IE7 or IE8 under Vista and Windows 7 as a screensaver?

Answer (score 1):

[RSS Screensaver](http://www.nuparadigm.com/Products/Toys/RssScreensaver/) allows you to add new feeds and choose a background to display them on for a screensaver, although it cannot read them directly from IE unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

[News Screensaver 2.2](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Screensavers/News-Screensaver.shtml) has the ability to import your feeds.

But its not freeware.

or You can use [2Flyer RSS screensaver](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Screensavers/2Flyer-RSS-Screensaver.shtml) or John T's one.